# Using basic definition to derive duplication formula for Gamma function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Baby Rudin chap 8, 8.21, some consequences of the gamma function, one of them is
$$\Gamma(x)=\frac{2^{x-1}}{\sqrt\pi}\Gamma(\frac{x}2)\Gamma(\frac{x+1}2)$$
Rudin noted that this identity "followed *directly* from $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi$ and from theorem 8.19", in which the theorem 8.19 is in fact a definition of the gamma function

> (1). $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$, for all $x>0$. 
>   (2). $\Gamma(1)=1$. 
>   (3).$\log\Gamma(x)$ is convex on $\Bbb R^+$.

And then I was having quite a hard time fighting to derive the duplication formula from this definition. I have to say that for me, it is NOT trivial or direct at all. I wonder, is there really a simple, or as Rudin put it, *direct* way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried calling the right-hand side of the identity $f(x)$, and then verifying (using known properties of $\Gamma$) that $f$ satisfies (1), (2) and (3)?

Comment: @HansLundmark Oh dear...yes this is surely what Rudin intended here!

Answer (score 2):

$$(2n)!=(2n)!!\cdot(2n-1)!!=2^n~n!~\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)=2^{2n}~n!~\prod_{k=1}^n\bigg(k-\dfrac12\bigg)=4^n~n!\cdot\frac{\bigg(n-\dfrac12\bigg)!}{\bigg(\dfrac12\bigg)!}$$

Comment: This is for $x$ an integer? And what does $(n+1/2)$ mean?

Comment: I don't see the connection with the question...

Comment: @AntonioHortaRibeiro: Are you objecting to the fact that the partial answer only directly covers the case when the argument is an even natural number, leaving it up to the reader to generalize the proof first to positive rationals, and then to positive reals ?

Comment: That is one point: I don't see a straight forward way to generalize to real numbers. Besides that  the answer ignore the framework the question was formulated on and does not try to use theorem 8.19.

In the end, @HanLundmark comment was what was actually helpful for me...

Comment: @AntonioHortaRibeiro: Reals and rationals are dense over the same interval.